# how to use all type of log modes in Custom Log file (Laravel 5.2 )

Tags: laravel, logging

laravel.log file is by default. all logs are stored. I need to create a different log file for a particular module where I can use any log level/log modes(warning, alert, notice, etc). I have found a few solutions but there is use only single log modes that will be dedicated to that module and that mode can't be used for other modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried monolog?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this after your question.

```
    // create a log channel
        $log = new Logger('name');
        $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/custom.log'), Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
        $log->warning('Foo');
        $log->error('Bar');
```

you will have to import below class;

```
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
```